# What will happen when multiple users modify the same column in rails 5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a movie booking feature. I have a column to store the number of tickets booked for the day.

When someone registers, I add 1 to the count, and when someone cancels, I subtract 1. But what happens if two people register at the same time? I'm not sure if the total count will be accurate. I'm using rails 5 and mysql. What technique should I use in this case?

Comment: Thats what proper DBMS's are for. MySLL will lock rows so the first to get there will lock the others out. once finished the others will get their turn. I suggest you read up on [MySQL record locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The usual Rails way to handle this is to use the [counter cache](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html) methods to increment or decrement the column. Normally you'd use the `:counter_cache` option on [`belongs_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):

> **`:counter_cache`**
> Caches the number of belonging objects on the associate class through the use of `CounterCache::ClassMethods#increment_counter` and `CounterCache::ClassMethods#decrement_counter`. The counter cache is incremented when an object of this class is created and decremented when it's destroyed. This requires that a column named `#{table_name}_count` (such as `comments_count` for a belonging `Comment` class) is used on the associate class (such as a `Post` class) - that is the migration for `#{table_name}_count` is created on the associate class (such that `Post.comments_count` will return the count cached, see note below). You can also specify a custom counter cache column by providing a column name instead of a true/false value to this option (e.g., `counter_cache: :my_custom_counter`.) Note: Specifying a counter cache will add it to that model's list of readonly attributes using `attr_readonly`.

The counter cache methods do direct `UPDATE`s in the database like:

```
update movies set counter_column = coalesce(counter_column, 0) + 1 where id = ...
```

so the counter maintenance should be atomic.

You'll probably have several things going on at once during registration so you'll want to wrap the whole process in a [transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
Movie.transaction do
  # Register user
  # Track payment
  # Whatever else is going on...
end
```